# Tracing on a plane the concurrent tangent lines of a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, projective-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth cubic algebraic surface in $\mathbb P^3(K)$, where $\mathrm{char} K = 0$. Is it true that if I take a point $P\in X$ and a plane $E$ general enough then the insterection points (I'd like to think of this as a "trace") of the lines with $E$ that cross $P$ and tangent to $X$ will be a smooth curve? I guess if $X$ is of degree $>3$ this is not necessarily true (there may be self-intersection of this curve). If so, what is the argument for this? I'd like to say that this is due to Bertini's theorem but I do not see this immediately. Also, is there a way to generalize this for $X$ of higher degree?

Answer (score 1):

The morphism
$$
\mathrm{Bl}_P(X) \to \mathbb{P}^2
$$
induced by the linear projection from $P$ is a flat double covering. Its ramification divisor $R \subset \mathrm{Bl}_P(X)$ is isomorphic to its branch divisor $B \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, and is equal to the fixed locus of the Galois involution of $\mathrm{Bl}_P(X)$. Therefore, it is smooth.

Comment: I'm sure it is a general result, but I don't know it so I ask. Why is the fixed locus of the Galois involution smooth? Altogether though, I feel that there is a more intuitive explanation than an arithmetic one.

Comment: There is nothing arithmetic here --- the Galois involution mentioned above is the involution of the double covering. The fixed locus is smooth, because the tangent bundle to the fixed locus is a direct summand (corresponding to the eigenvalue 1) of the restriction of the tangent bundle of the ambient variety, hence it is locally free.

Comment: My impression is that this argument is independent of the choice of the plane. I believe this is not true if the chosen plane is not general enough.

Comment: Of course it is independent. In fact, the projection out of $P$ induces an isomorphism between any pair of planes (not passing through $P$) compatible with your "traces". Moreover, all these planes are isomorphic to the abstract plane, parameterizing lines through $P$, which is the right way to think of the linear projection.